# Is there a shortcut for selecting a word under cursor in Gedit?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, selection, shortcut, gedit

Pretty much what the title says. I know this can be done in the likes of SublimeText but was wondering if it was also possible in Gedit. Currently I'm using:

```
Ctrl+Shift+Arrows
```

To select things but this hardly seems optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way that works with Gedit 3.10.3!
I have installed [Gmate](https://github.com/gmate)'s collection of plugins.

One of them, called "[Line Tools Plugin](https://github.com/gmate/gmate/tree/master/plugins/gedit3/line_tools)" has a shorcut for selecting words (Ctrl+M).

Answer (score 0):

install this plugin for selecting word under cursor:

https://code.google.com/p/gedit-click-config/

Comment: This works great up until Gedit 3.7x but I'm using Gedit 3.10.3 :[